# C++ Error at end of the main() regarding Error Handling

Tags: c++, exception

```
void main(){
    try {
        GameEntry deletedItem = newList.remove(13);
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBound &e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    cout << ":)";
}
```

At this source code, after error handing at `catch()`, main function successfully puts ":)", but unknown error occurs at end line of the `main()` function.
I know that how to fix this error by putting `exit(0)` after `cout << ":)"`, but I don't know the reason.
Is there any difference between `return` and `exit` regarding Error-handling? and Do I have to use `int main()`, not `void main()` when I use `try catch` block?

[solved]
I found that there was a error in destructor of a class.

Comment: You must always use `int main`.

Comment: Yes, you must use `int main(...)`, but it wouldn't be causing the crash (I guess there is a crash?). Without MCVE, have no clue what could be the crash reason.

Comment: There's one or more bugs in one or more of `GameEntry`, `IndexOutOfBound`, and whatever type `newList` is.

Comment: I found that there was a error in destructor of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that how to fix this error by putting exit(0) after cout << ":)"

This does not fix the error.
The error is just hidden because the code causing the error is not run.

When you call `exit()` it does not return from the call. This means the stack is not unwound and thus local objects are not destroyed. This suggests that you have a bug the destructor of one of your local objects.

Unfortunately you did not show any objects so it is hard to tell you what the error is.

```
void main(){

    // You have some variables declared here.
    // That get destroyed when main() exists (ie there destructors run).
    // This is where you bug is.
    // calling exit() after the last line below will hide this error
    // as the destructor for these objects will not be run.

    try {
        GameEntry deletedItem = newList.remove(13);
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBound &e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    cout << ":)";
}
```

Is there any difference between return and exit regarding Error-handling?

The only major difference is that automatic variables are not destroyed (because exit does not return and thus the stack is not unwound). Everything else is the same.

> Do I have to use int main(), not void main() when I use try catch block?

Using `void main()` is not valid.

The only valid versions of a program have a main declared like this:

```
int main()
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])  // or equivalent types.
```

Any other declaration is non standard (though allowed).

Notes:

> **6.8.3.1 main function**
>   1: A program shall contain a global function called main. Executing a program starts a main thread of execution in which the main function is invoked, and in which variables of static storage duration might be initialized and destroyed. It is implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main function.
>   2: An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. Its type shall have C++ language linkage and it shall have a declared return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. An implementation shall allow both
>
> — a function of () returning int and
>
> — a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int
>
> 3: The function main shall not be used within a program. The linkage of main is implementation-defined. A program that defines main as deleted or that declares main to be inline, static, or constexpr is ill-formed. The main function shall not be declared with a linkage-specification. A program that declares a variable main at global scope or that declares the name main with C language linkage (in any namespace) is ill-formed. The name main is not otherwise reserved.

Comment: "Any other declaration of main causes the program to be ill-defined."  - don't think so - maybe implementation-defined. Certainly free-standing implementations can do more or less what they like.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Fixed: I know better than to argue against your knowledge.

Comment: I found that there was a error in destructor of a class. Sorry for not posting full source code.

Answer (score 0):

Handling this error has nothing to do with the return type of main. It should always be `int main()`.

The difference between `return` and `exit()`:

- **`return`** Destructors are called for your scoped variables
- **`exit()`** No destructors are called except for static variables

So you should use `exit()` carefully.